# Silverlight WCF services calls for weird URL on server

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, iis, endpoint

I have a problem with Silverlight 4 and WCF.

I'm debugging my Silverlight application that should connect to `https://MYSERVERNAME/mijn/DataSource/Editie.svc/` instead it always requests `https://WRONGSERVERNAME/mijn/DataSource/Editie.svc/$metadata`.

It is really wierd, I searched through all my code and I never use the servername `WRONGSERVERNAME`. Furthermore, also `https://MYSERVERNAME/mijn/DataSource/Editie.svc/$metadata` gives a `404` error, so even if `WRONGSERVERNAME` would respond the request would still produce a `404` error.

Does anyone has this error as well?

Answer (score 0):

try removing and adding a service reference through Visual Studio if you can. It´s the safest bet. WCF server and client configuration really needs to match to work. WCF service projects usually have a IMetaDateExchange behavior. Wrong server name might just be a case of a wrong endpoint entry in web.config